# Spark Dataframe suddenly become very slow when I reuse the old cached data iteratively too much time

Tags: caching, apache-spark, dataframe, iteration, reusability

The problem happened when I try to keep my cached result in a List and try to calculate new DataFrame by all the data from the last list in each iteration. However, Even I use an empty DataFrame and get an empty result each time, the function will suddenly get very slow after about 8~12 round.

Here is my code

```
testLoop(Nil)
def testLoop(lastDfList:List[DataFrame]){      
  // do some dummy transformation like union and cache the result
  val resultDf = lastDfList.foldLeft(Seq[Data]().toDF){(df, lastDf) => df.union(lastDf)}.cache        

  // always get 0, of course  
  println(resultDf.count)  

  // benchmark action
  benchmark(resultDf.count)    

  testLoop(resultDf::lastDfList)
}
```

the benchmark result

`1~6 round : < 200ms
7 round : 367ms
8 round : 918ms
9 round : 2476ms
10 round : 7833ms
11 round : 24231ms`

I don't think GC or Block eviction is the problem in my case since I already use an empty DataFrame, but I don't know what is the cause? Do I misunderstand the meaning of cache or something?

Thanks!

---

After reading ImDarrenG's solution, I changed my code to be the following:

```
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("/tmp")

testLoop(Nil)
def testLoop(lastDfList:List[DataFrame]){      
  // do some dummy transformation like union and cache the result
  val resultDf = lastDfList.foldLeft(Seq[Data]().toDF){(df, lastDf) => df.union(lastDf)}.cache        

  resultDf.checkpoint()  

  // always get 0, of course  
  println(resultDf.count)  

  // benchmark action
  benchmark(resultDf.count)    

  testLoop(resultDf::lastDfList)
}
```

But it still become very slow after a few iterations.

Answer (score 3):

Here you create a list of `DataFrames` by adding `resultDf` to the beginning of `lastDfList` and pass that to the next iteration of `testLoop`:

```
testLoop(resultDf::lastDfList)
```

So `lastDfList` gets longer each pass.

This line creates a new `DataFrame` by `union`ing each member of `lastDfList`:

```
val resultDf = lastDfList.foldLeft(Seq[Data]().toDF){(df, lastDf) => df.union(lastDf))}.cache
```

Each member of `lastDfList` is a union of it's predecessors, therefore, Spark is maintaining a lineage that becomes exponentially larger with each pass of `testLoop`.

I expect that the increase in time is caused by the housekeeping of the DAG. Caching the dataframes removes the need to repeat transformations, but the lineage must still be maintained by spark.

Cached data or no, it looks like you are building a really complex DAG by unioning each `DataFrame` with all of it's predecessors with each pass of `testLoop`.

You could use `checkpoint` to trim the lineage, and introduce some check to prevent infinite recursion.

Comment: Thanks! you give me the right direction. However, even I set my checkpoint directory by ```spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("/tmp");``` and add resultDf.checkpoint() right after ``` val resultDf = lastDfList.foldLeft(...){...}.cache ```. The problem is still there, it will become unbearable slow after about 8 iterations. I can see those checkpoint data on my directory /tmp but they didn't seem to help.

Comment: Look at the output of `toDebugString`, what you are doing creates a very complex DAG. Slowing down is expected given the logical complexity of your code.

Comment: I know the problem is that my DAG is too complex after times of iterations, but the API document says that the checkpoint can be used to truncate the logical plan of the Dataset, so I think it may help my situation. However, it is not :(, I look at the information from debugString and explain and see that the DAG still grows larger and larger after each iteration.

Comment: At 24 seconds to union 12 dataframes, cache the resulting dataframe, checkpoint it to disk, and do a collect operation, works out at somewhere around 2 seconds per union, while not exactly blazing fast, it also doesn't feel unreasonable. What size of cluster (cores/mem/executors) are you using?

Comment: I test it in my local machine - Intel 17, 16G Memory. 2 second is acceptable of course, however, my problem is that the time will start to grow exponentially after like 7 iterations. I thought the checkpoint method should solve the problem of growing and make each iteration spending almost same time.

Comment: It's impossible for each iteration to take the same time because you are adding another dateframe to the list to be unioned each iteration.

Comment: OK, that's true, but it should at least grow linearly if the checkpoint really help me cached all the complex DAGs before. So it should not spend 2xx ms in the start and grow to 2xxxx ms after only 10 iterations.

Answer (score 1):

According to [API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset) and [code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/12ab7f7e89ec9e102859ab3b710815d3058a2e8d/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L544), `checkpoint` will return a new Dataset instead of changing original Dataset.